# jQuery copy input val to other input and replace characters

Tags: jquery, regex, replace

I got the following problem and I did not find any solution.

I have to input fields: "label" and "url".

When you write something into the label field it should be duplicated into the url field.
This works like a charm, but I need the url field to be (url_encoded or sanitized) rather it would like to replace special characters with customized ones e.g. 'ä' with 'ae' or ' ' with '+'.
I figured I could just use a RegEx function to replace things like ä or é but I do not get it right.

Can you tell me how I can do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/Shaz/bwKZt/

Comment: Hey, thanks, that is one step in a very good direction. But I just noticed that I did not put my question right.
I need the function to replace certain characters before it encodes the text. I want to replace letters like 'ä' with an 'ae', and 'ö' with an 'oe' and so one and encode it afterwords, because otherwise it will get very untidy. The urlencode is supposed to ensure that all the characters not exchanged will be sanitized. If you could tell me how I can add this my problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

```
var h = function(){
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function(){ $("#url").val(encodeURIComponent($(self).val())); }, 5);
};
$("#label").change(h).keydown(h);
```